# CSS - avoiding repeatition

Tags: css

I have the following CSS which makes a speech bubble. 
It works perfectly. 
My issue though is that I want to have different colored speech bubbles on the page.

I apply the class triangle-border1 to a P tag. Of course, inline I can just change `border:5px solid #F7827B;` to whatever color I choose. But the class makes use of pseudo elements which cannot be changed inline.

I therefore have 7 copies of the same CSS class, numbered 1-7, the only difference being the color! This seems the wrong way to go about things.

Does anyone have any knowledge of how to achieve this without repeated CSS?

Thanks

```
.triangle-border1 {
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  margin:1em 0 1em;
  border:5px solid #F7827B;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.triangle-border1:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; 
  left:40px; 
  border-width:20px 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-bottom:0px white solid;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  border-left-color:transparent;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-top-color:#F7827B;
}
.triangle-border1:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-10px; 
  left:47px; 
  border-width:13px 13px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-bottom:0px white solid;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  border-left-color:transparent;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-top-color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variable like this:

```css
.triangle-border {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1em 0 1em;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid var(--c,#fff);
}

.triangle-border:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 40px;
  border-width: 20px 20px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  color:transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px white solid;
  border-top-color: var(--c,#fff);
}

.triangle-border:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 47px;
  border-width: 13px 13px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  color:transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px white solid;
  border-top-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-border" style="--c:pink"></div>
<div class="triangle-border" style="--c:blue"></div>
<div class="triangle-border" style="--c:red"></div>
<div class="triangle-border" style="--c:black"></div>
```

Comment: that is absolutely spot on what I was looking for! I'm always looking for ways to reduce my lines of repeated code and this is brilliant! I wasn't aware of CSS variables, but I'll be using them extensively now! Many thanks.

Comment: @Jack and the magic with CSS variable is that you can put property on the pseudo element ;)

Comment: sadly the CSS variables are not supported by WKHTMLTOPDF, so alas for this particular project I have to list out all the CSS... but definitely using this for other things.

Answer (score 1):

The best way as I can see is use the different class on elements for just border color like

```css
.triangle-border {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1em 0 1em;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.triangle-border:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 40px;
  border-width: 20px 20px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: 0px white solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.triangle-border:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 47px;
  border-width: 13px 13px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: 0px white solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #FFF;
}

.triangle-border.color1 {
  border: 5px solid #F7827B;
}

.triangle-border.color2 {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.triangle-border.color3 {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.triangle-border.color4 {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.triangle-border.color1:before {
  border-top-color: #F7827B;
}

.triangle-border.color2:before {
  border-top-color: red;
}

.triangle-border.color3:before {
  border-top-color: blue;
}

.triangle-border.color4:before {
  border-top-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-border color1"></div>
<div class="triangle-border color2"></div>
<div class="triangle-border color3"></div>
<div class="triangle-border color4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your css in 2 different classes. One for the shape and one for the color:

```
<div class="triangle-border1 triangle-color1"></div>
```

Then just add another css class below your existing ones:

```
.triangle-color1 {
  border:5px solid #F7827B;
}
.triangle-color1:before {
  border-top-color: #F7827B;
}
.triangle-color1:after {
  border-top-color: #F7827B;
}
```

In this second class, you can override whatever property you want from your existing CSS classes.